# Connect Android / MySQL with JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, database-connection

I have an application that try to connect to MySQL with JDBC by the following code in the MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{   

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     

    Spinner s = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1,
            int position, long arg3) {
        if(position == 0)
            {}

        if(position == 1)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setClass(MainActivity.this, Resultados.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

        if(position == 2)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setClass(MainActivity.this, Clasificacion.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }); 

    @Override
     protected void onCreate1(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sqlThread.start();
    }

    @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
     return true;
    }

     Thread sqlThread = new Thread() {
     public void run() {
     try {
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

     Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
     "jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.4:3306/fifa", "root", "root");

     String stsql = "Select version()";
     Statement st = conn.createStatement();
     ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(stsql);
     rs.next();
     System.out.println( rs.getString(1) );
     conn.close();
     } catch (SQLException se) {
     System.out.println("oops! No se puede conectar. Error: " + se.toString());
     } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

     }
     }
     };

}
```

I have one error on this line, how can I fix it?

```
protected void onCreate1(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

Neither is exactly this way if I can get the connection to the database, is it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before `protected void onCreate1(Bundle savedInstanceState) {` you should have an enclosing `}`, of the method `onCreate()`.